# How can I remove Chrome app (not Chrome itself)?

Tags: google-chrome, chrome-extensions

Once I've installed Postman app for Chrome. Then they deployed native mac os app and Chrome version was deprecated. The problem is that I don't have Postman in the list of installed apps in Chrome so now I have no idea how to remove it. Both native app and Chrome version now is shown in my Spotlight